# PlayN and compatibility

Tags: java, android, playn

On some phones, I can't execute a PlayN project. Every time I get :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10336): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(10336): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: playn.android.GameViewGL.setEGLContextClientVersion
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at playn.android.GameViewGL.<init>(GameViewGL.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at playn.android.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:73)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
E/AndroidRuntime(10336):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process ( 2238): Sending signal. PID: 10336 SIG: 3
```

I got it on the Samsung Galaxy S1 and the Acer A500. But works fine on Google Nexus S.

Comment: It seems that PlayN needs platform >= 8 : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLContextClientVersion(int)

Answer (score 2):

it need a device that have a GPU that suports openGL20 *or* openGL20 emulated in software (several models made in china do this)

Comment: yes, I figured it out. And it needs android >= 2.2. Because some GLES 2 methods appear only in this version. That's a pity for the 2D games that don't need openGL20 to work.